# Run time and theta notation

Tags: runtime, big-o

for the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 for(j=2;j<n;j++)
  {
      c[i][j]=0;
       for(k=0;k<n;k++)
       c[i][j]=a[i][k]*b[k][j];
  }
```

I would say the run time is theta(n^3), as I see in the k loop, there is two n (n^3) and on the other loop, another n, making it n^3. Would this be right or what did I miss.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, formatted:

```
for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j=2; j < n; j++) {
        c[i][j] = 0;
        for (k=0; k < n;k++)
            c[i][j] = a[i][k]*b[k][j];
    }
}
```

The outer loop in `i` only iterates 5 times, and so can just be treated as a constant penalty as far as complexity is concerned.  The inner two loops in `j` and `k` are independent of each other, and both are `O(n)`.  We can therefore just multiple the complexities to get `O(n^2)` for the overall running time as a function of `n`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would the run time just be theta(n^2)? I realized i is only running 5 times where I dont see a constant for k, j, and n.

Comment: The outer loop runs a constant amount, and therefore is not considered part of the complexity.